# How should I authenticate the Azure CLI for access without SAS?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azcopy

I'm playing around with the Azure CLI (`az` and `azcopy`), and I'm finding that simple operations like copying simply aren't working, though using Azure Explorer is okay.

Whereas I was able to use the AWS CLI seamlessly (eg, `aws s3 cp local_file.txt s3://my-bucket/`), trying to do the same with `az` after creating the account and a blob fails. For example:

```
./azcopy copy "./hello.txt" "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/"
```

This fails, telling me that:

> RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission

However, I successfully logged in with `./azcopy login --tenant-id myTenantId` (which, according to the documentation, seems like it should store OAuth information for subsequent calls to the CLI). And from the portal, looking at my subscription, I am marked an owner. Additionally, if I generate a SAS that has read/write access, I can copy files into my container when including the query string.

For day-to-day interaction, I don't want to have to include all the extra arguments such as `--from-to=LocalBlob` or the SAS query string. How can I avoid all this boilerplate?

Additionally, the `az` all-in-one doesn't seem to allow copy operations such as `az storage blob copy hello.txt "https://myaccount...". How can this be used easily used?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to assign either the **`storage blob data contributor`** or the **`Storage Blob Data Owner`** role to the account like below:

[image]

**I am able to copy the file from successfully like below:**

```bash
azcopy copy "C:\Users\testcer" "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername"
```

[image]

In the Azure Portal, file is successfully uploaded like below:

[image]

To know how to use **`az storage blob copy`**, please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start)

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Rukmini. I am already the owner of this resource and have ownership permissions on the entire subscription. I explicitly granted myself `Storage Blob Data Owner` permissions (even though, as I said, I am already `Owner`), but still the copy operation fails.

Comment: Can you please include the snips of what are you trying?